# How do you loop through a range of numbers and apply it to every variable?

Tags: r, loops

I have the following data frame:

```
A1_Q1 <- c(1, 2, 3)
A1_Q2 <- c(4, 5, 6)
A1_Q3 <- c(7, 8, 9)
A1_Q4 <- c(10, 11, 12)
A1_Q5 <- c(13, 14, 15)
A1_Q6 <- c(16, 17, 18)

A2_Q1 <- c(1, 2, 3)
A2_Q2 <- c(4, 5, 6)
A2_Q3 <- c(7, 8, 9)
A2_Q4 <- c(10, 11, 12)
A2_Q5 <- c(13, 14, 15)
A2_Q6 <- c(16, 17, 18)

df <- data.frame(A1_Q1, A1_Q2, A1_Q3, A1_Q4, A1_Q5, A1_Q6,
                 A2_Q1, A2_Q2, A2_Q3, A2_Q4, A2_Q5, A2_Q6)
```

I want to create additional variables called `col1a, col1b, col1c`.

```
df <- df %>%
  unite("col1a",
        A1_Q1,
        A1_Q2,
        sep="-",
        remove = FALSE) %>%
  unite("col1b",
        A1_Q3,
        A1_Q4,
        sep="-",
        remove = FALSE) %>%
  unite("col1c",
        A1_Q5,
        A1_Q6,
        sep="-",
        remove = FALSE)
```

I also want to do the same thing for the A2 variables.

Is there any way I can also create variables called `col2a, col2b, col2c` in one go? I'm envisioning a for loop that looks something like this:

```
for (i in 1:2) {
  df <- df %>%
    unite("colia",
          Ai_Q1,
          Ai_Q2,
          sep="-",
          remove = FALSE) %>%
    unite("colib",
          Ai_Q3,
          Ai_Q4,
          sep="-",
          remove = FALSE) %>%
    unite("colic",
          Ai_Q5,
          Ai_Q6,
          sep="-",
          remove = FALSE) 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's another solution:

1. Use `paste0` and `[[` to access the cols without hard-coding the index.
2. Use `map_dfc` to iterate, have `.x` as index and get a data.frame with the new cols.
3. Call `map_dfc` from within `mutate` to have the new cols automatically bound to the data.frame.

```r
library(tidyverse)

A1_Q1 <- c(1, 2, 3)
A1_Q2 <- c(4, 5, 6)
A1_Q3 <- c(7, 8, 9)
A1_Q4 <- c(10, 11, 12)
A1_Q5 <- c(13, 14, 15)
A1_Q6 <- c(16, 17, 18)

A2_Q1 <- c(1, 2, 3)
A2_Q2 <- c(4, 5, 6)
A2_Q3 <- c(7, 8, 9)
A2_Q4 <- c(10, 11, 12)
A2_Q5 <- c(13, 14, 15)
A2_Q6 <- c(16, 17, 18)

df <- data.frame(A1_Q1, A1_Q2, A1_Q3, A1_Q4, A1_Q5, A1_Q6,
                 A2_Q1, A2_Q2, A2_Q3, A2_Q4, A2_Q5, A2_Q6)

df %>%
  mutate(
    map_dfc(
      1:2,
      ~ {
        cols <- list(
          paste(
            df[[paste0("A", .x, "_Q1")]],
            df[[paste0("A", .x, "_Q2")]],
            sep = "-"
          ),
          paste(
            df[[paste0("A", .x, "_Q3")]],
            df[[paste0("A", .x, "_Q4")]],
            sep = "-"
          ),
          paste(
            df[[paste0("A", .x, "_Q5")]],
            df[[paste0("A", .x, "_Q6")]],
            sep = "-"
          )
        )
        
        names(cols) <- c(
          paste0("col", .x, "a"),
          paste0("col", .x, "b"),
          paste0("col", .x, "c")
        )
        
        cols
          
      }
    )
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use the regex `^A1` and `^A2` to `grep` the columns subset `sb`; to create it, we loop using `lapply` over the numbers `1:2` and use `sprintf` (the advantage is, it's safe not to confuse `A1` and `A2` columns, and we can use the numbers later for the new column names). In the second step we basically `paste0` the respective two columns together, e.g. `sb[(1:2) + x]` for the first two `sb` columns together, and increment it by `2` until `ncol(sb)` is reached. At the end of an iteration we `paste0` `col`, number `x` and according element of `letters` constant to a string to `setNames`. Finally, we simply `cbind` the resulting list to the data frame.

```
res <- lapply(1:2, \(x) {
  sb <- df[grep(sprintf('^A%s', x), names(df))]
  lapply((0:((ncol(sb) - 1)/2))*2, \(x) Reduce(\(y, z) paste0(y, '-', z), sb[(1:2) + x])) |>
    setNames(paste0('col', x, letters[seq_len((ncol(sb))/2)]))
}) |> cbind(df)

res
#   col1a col1b col1c col2a col2b col2c A1_Q1 A1_Q2 A1_Q3 A1_Q4 A1_Q5 A1_Q6 A2_Q1
# 1   1-4  7-10 13-16   1-4  7-10 13-16     1     4     7    10    13    16     1
# 2   2-5  8-11 14-17   2-5  8-11 14-17     2     5     8    11    14    17     2
# 3   3-6  9-12 15-18   3-6  9-12 15-18     3     6     9    12    15    18     3
#   A2_Q2 A2_Q3 A2_Q4 A2_Q5 A2_Q6
# 1     4     7    10    13    16
# 2     5     8    11    14    17
# 3     6     9    12    15    18
```

Note, that this might need a preprocessing step, if the `A*` are not so nicely sorted by `Q` as shown in your example.

### Update

For old R versions, use this code (but better always use updated software).

```
res <- cbind(lapply(1:2, function(x) {
  sb <- df[grep(sprintf('^A%s', x), names(df))]
  lapply((0:((ncol(sb) - 1)/2))*2, function(x) Reduce(function(y, z) paste0(y, '-', z), sb[(1:2) + x])) |>
    setNames(paste0('col', x, letters[seq_len((ncol(sb))/2)]))
}), df)
```

Comment: I got an error `Error: unexpected input in "res <- lapply(1:2, \"`

Comment: @hy9fesh You need to update your R, then it works. Please see updated answer.

Answer (score -1):

Create the names for the output columns ('nm1') from the substring of the column names, split the data into a `list` of consecutive pairs of columns with `split.default` by using an index created with `gl`, loop over the `list` with `lapply` and `paste` the columns in the `list` rowwise with `do.call` and assign the output `list` to new columns in the data

```
nm1 <-  paste0("col", rep(unique( sub(".(\\d+)_.*", "\\1", 
      names(df))), each = 3), letters[1:3])
df[nm1] <-  lapply(split.default(df, as.integer(gl(ncol(df), 2, ncol(df)))), 
      function(x) do.call(paste, c(x, sep = '-')))
```

-output

```
> df
  A1_Q1 A1_Q2 A1_Q3 A1_Q4 A1_Q5 A1_Q6 A2_Q1 A2_Q2 A2_Q3 A2_Q4 A2_Q5 A2_Q6 col1a col1b col1c col2a col2b col2c
1     1     4     7    10    13    16     1     4     7    10    13    16   1-4  7-10 13-16   1-4  7-10 13-16
2     2     5     8    11    14    17     2     5     8    11    14    17   2-5  8-11 14-17   2-5  8-11 14-17
3     3     6     9    12    15    18     3     6     9    12    15    18   3-6  9-12 15-18   3-6  9-12 15-18
```

---

An option in `tidyverse` is to reshape into 'long' format with `pivot_longer`, split the name column into two with `separate`, create the 'a', 'b', 'c' values from the Q values with `case_when`, `unite` the columns, reshape back to wide format with `pivot_wider` and bind with the original data

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)
df %>% 
  mutate(rn = row_number()) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -rn) %>%
  separate(name, into = c("name1", "name2")) %>%
  mutate( name2 = case_when(name2 %in% c("Q1", "Q2") ~ "a", 
     name2 %in% c("Q3", "Q4") ~ "b", TRUE ~ "c")) %>% 
  group_by(rn, name1, name2) %>% 
  summarise(value = str_c(value, collapse = '-'), .groups = 'drop') %>%
   mutate(name1 = str_replace(name1, "\\D+", "col")) %>%
   unite(name, name1, name2, sep = "") %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = name, values_from = value) %>% 
  select(-rn) %>% 
  bind_cols(df, .)
```

-output

```
 A1_Q1 A1_Q2 A1_Q3 A1_Q4 A1_Q5 A1_Q6 A2_Q1 A2_Q2 A2_Q3 A2_Q4 A2_Q5 A2_Q6 col1a col1b col1c col2a col2b col2c
1     1     4     7    10    13    16     1     4     7    10    13    16   1-4  7-10 13-16   1-4  7-10 13-16
2     2     5     8    11    14    17     2     5     8    11    14    17   2-5  8-11 14-17   2-5  8-11 14-17
3     3     6     9    12    15    18     3     6     9    12    15    18   3-6  9-12 15-18   3-6  9-12 15-18
```

---

Or another easier option is to subset the alternating columns with a recycling logical vector, loop over the corresponding columns with `Map`, `paste` and assign back to create new columns

```
df[nm1] <- Map(function(x, y) paste(x, y, sep = "-"), df[c(TRUE, FALSE)], 
        df[c(FALSE, TRUE)])
```

-output

```
> df
  A1_Q1 A1_Q2 A1_Q3 A1_Q4 A1_Q5 A1_Q6 A2_Q1 A2_Q2 A2_Q3 A2_Q4 A2_Q5 A2_Q6 col1a col1b col1c col2a col2b col2c
1     1     4     7    10    13    16     1     4     7    10    13    16   1-4  7-10 13-16   1-4  7-10 13-16
2     2     5     8    11    14    17     2     5     8    11    14    17   2-5  8-11 14-17   2-5  8-11 14-17
3     3     6     9    12    15    18     3     6     9    12    15    18   3-6  9-12 15-18   3-6  9-12 15-18
```

Comment: Could you please provide some more information as to what the code is doing in each line?